# Hide custom field label on the order edit page (backend), if it is empty in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the following code to display field label for "shipping_company" field, on the edit page.

```
// Display field value for shipping company field 
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'delivery_date_and_time', 10, 1 );
function delivery_date_and_time($order){
  echo '<p><strong>'.__('Delivery Date & Time').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 
'_shipping_company', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

Now, I'm trying to hide the label, if it was not filled by the customer, when they placed the order.

Comment: you could add an if condition to `get_post_meta`, if NOT empty.. echo..

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment.

Something like this?

    if get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_shipping_company', true  ) ) {

I'm missing something...

Comment: See my answer, this should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an if condition to `get_post_meta`, if NOT empty.. echo

```php
// Display field value for shipping company field 
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'delivery_date_and_time', 10, 1 );
function delivery_date_and_time($order) {
    $shipping_company = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_shipping_company', true );
    
    // NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $shipping_company ) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Delivery Date & Time', 'woocommerce' ) . ':</strong> ' . $shipping_company . '</p>';
    }
}
```